# Fetching callback value and using it inside another async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, puppeteer

I have a Node.js application which is connected to MongoDb. I am retrieving a certain json from my mongodb collection using `findOne()` so the value is obtained in a callback. My application also has browser automation tasks using puppeteer. To fill in a certain input field I am trying to use the json that I retrieved from mongodb collection. But due to the asynchronous nature I am unable to use the callback value outside the function. I need to use the callback value to send as an input for the puppeteer.

I have tried to fetch the value from `findOne()` callback using another function but still unable to use it for the puppeteer async function.

**The below code fetches the value from mongodb:**

```
var g;


db.collection("users").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    storedata(result);  

});

function  storedata (x){
    g = x;
    //console.log(g);
}
```

**Puppeteer code:**

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();          

    await page.goto('http://0.0.0.0:4200/')

    await page.$eval('[placeholder="BPMN xml"]', el => {
        return el.value = g
    })
})()
```

I always get the error `g is not defined`. Of course, I understand that scope of g is within the function but even when I tried to place the puppeteer code inside the function `storedata()` I get g undefined error. Kindly help me in understanding the callback values in a better way.

Comment: But where is `g` defined? It's nowhere in your code.

Comment: Is the pupeteer code in the same file as your mongoDB code?

Comment: @ThomasDondorf I have defined in the top section but havent shown here. I then assigned the value of g = x thinking that it will simply override the value.

Comment: @dar Yes. It is both in the same file app.js

Comment: Try explicitly passing 'g' into your anonymous Puppeteer code and then again into your 'page.$eval()' call back. Does it recognize 'g' then?

Comment: @dar yes this works. Thomas Dondorf has given the same solution and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you pass `g` to the browser environment. The variable only exists inside your Node.js environment, but you explicitly have to pass it to the browser environment so that you can use it.

**Quote from the docs** (third argument for [`page.$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1)):

> `...args` <...Serializable|JSHandle> Arguments to pass to `pageFunction`

**Code Sample:**

```js
await page.$eval('[placeholder="BPMN xml"]', (el, g) => {
    return el.value = g
}, g);
```

You pass g as a third argument, which will then become your second argument in your function inside the page.